# React Native fetch is not working

Tags: react-native

```
try {
  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {

    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("REQ ERROR::: " + error);
    });
} catch (ex) {
  console.error("REQ ERROR::: " + JSON.stringify(ex));
}
```

But the log says

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'self.fetch')

How to solve this ?

Comment: Your code looks valid. This maybe a long shot, but check: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#app-transport-security. However it also sounds that `self` is not defined, but your code example only shows plain `fetch` (so no idea, where **self** comes from).

Comment: @zvona yeah.. I've also no idea where self comes from.

Comment: Add more code, the whole function if possible.

Comment: @Tooble did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an issue with the `npm` & `builder` cache. You must be having another dependency depending on `whatwg-fetch`.

Which you can easily check with `npm ls whatwg-fetch`.

Remove the dependency which is using `whatwg-fetch` reinstall it. Also clear the builder cache. If you're using expo `expo start -c`

You'll find some solution stating to do: `global.self = global`. Which is not really a solution.